# dfferential equation with $df/dt = e^{\alpha f}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone show me how to solve this kind of differential equation?
$\frac{df}{dt}=e^{\alpha f}$, with$f(0) = 0$ and $Re(\alpha)<0$.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Separable diff equation
$$\frac{df}{dt}=e^{\alpha f}\\\frac{df}{e^{\alpha f}}=dt \\ 
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{df}{e^{\alpha f}} =\int_{0}^{t} ds \\
\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\alpha f}df =\int_{0}^{t} ds \\
e^{-\alpha f}|^t_0=s|^t_0\\
e^{-\alpha f(t)}-e^{-\alpha f(0)}=t
\\e^{-\alpha f(t)}-e^{-\alpha (0)}=t\\
e^{-\alpha f(t)}-1=t\\
e^{-\alpha f(t)}=1+t\\
e^{+\alpha f(t)}=\dfrac{1}{1+t}\\$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful.